# Covariance of normally distributed random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, covariance

If $ X \sim N(0,1) $ and given  $ X = x $ then  $ Y \sim N(x,1) $

I want to find the $ Cov(X,Y) $ using the relationship stated above.

My attempt:

$ Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]    \\ 
E[X] = 0\\
Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] \\
E[XY] = E[E[XY|X=x]]$

I am not sure how to proceed from there..
Do I integrate the joint distribution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$E[XY] = E[XE[Y|X]]
$$
Now as $E[Y|X] = X$:
$$
= E[X^2] = 1
$$
and 
$$
E[X]E[Y] = 0
$$

you get $cov(X,Y) = 1$.

Answer (score -1):

You should be careful with your conditioning. What is true that $E[XY] = E[E[XY|X]]$, and *not* $E[XY]=E[E[XY|X=x]]$.

So with $E[XY] = E[E[XY|X]]$, you can integrate with respect to the distribution of $X$.

$E[E[XY|X]] = \int E[XY|X=x]f_X(x)dx.$